# Prove convergence from $|\sum_{k = 1}^n a_k |\leq \sqrt{n}$

Tags: real-analysis

Given  $|\sum_{k = 1}^n a_k |\leq \sqrt{n}$, how to show that $\sum_{k = 1}^\infty a_k/k $ converges?.

I've not encountered a convergence problem where I don't know the convergence of $(a_n)$. So the usual test are out of option.

Comment: Use [Dirichlet's test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_test)

Comment: @YadatiKiran, but $M$ is a constant the bound here is changing for each $n$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $\displaystyle s_n=\sum_{k=1}^{n} a_k$. $\:$ Then $\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{n} \dfrac {a_k} k = \sum_{k=1}^{n} \dfrac {s_k-s_{k-1}} k $ (with the convention $s_0=0$).  $\:$ This can be rewritten as $\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} s_k (\frac 1 k -\frac 1 {k+1})+\frac {s_n} n$. $\:$  It remains only to observe that $\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \sqrt k (\frac 1 k -\frac 1 {k+1})=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \sqrt k \frac 1 {k(k+1)}$ is convergent by comparison with $\displaystyle\sum k^{-3/2}$.

Comment: Is there an instance when we know to invoke this telescoping $\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac {a_k} k = \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac {s_k-s_{k-1}} k$ technique?

Comment: @Hawk The fact that we are given  abound on the sums $s_k$ and not directly on the coefficients suggests that you should write $a_k=s_k-s_{k-1}$ and proceed as I have done. This technique is very powerful (especially in Fourier series).

Comment: Thank you for showing me this trick.